# Using ranch, how can I tell when a listener is terminated?

Tags: erlang, ranch

I'm writing a TCP server in Erlang, using [Ranch](https://github.com/extend/ranch). The clients will reconnect immediately the connection is dropped, which means that one particular failure mode is listeners being started and killed dozens of times a second.

I'd like to detect this happening and publish statistics to statsd, for monitoring in production.

So, can I use something in Ranch to monitor when a listener is recycled? Or can I use something in Erlang to monitor process mortality for the entire node, without having to link to each process, and where those processes were started by some other supervisor, so I don't have a reference to them?

Comment: I would actually go about this using process_flag(trap_exit, true) in your protocol definition. That way you can have the process update statsd itself in a terminate routine. The easiest way to go about this may be to turn your protocol handler into a gen_server (because gen_server automatically catches callbacks), as demonstrated here: http://ninenines.eu/docs/en/ranch/HEAD/guide/protocols/

Comment: Could you clarify this, please? I'm having trouble understanding how the protocol traps itself crashing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a direct answer to my question, but I opted, instead, to have a separate process periodically polling `ranch_server:count_connections(my_ref)`, and publish that to statsd.